# How to get a value from class in StatefulWidget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and i have some codes to build textfield. i want to make an initial value in textfield but this is from input in another class.

```
class TextFieldEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  TextFieldEdit({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.hintTxt,
    required this.controller,
    required this.defaultTxt,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title, hintTxt;
  final controller;
  final defaultTxt;

  @override
  State<TextFieldEdit> createState() => _TextFieldEditState();
}

class _TextFieldEditState extends State<TextFieldEdit> {
  
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = defaultTxt;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
}
```

in `_TextFieldEditState` class at the _controller.text i want to get value from `defaultTxt` in `TextFieldEdit` class. But how can i send it to `_TextFieldEditState` class?

the error message is : Undefined name 'defaultTxt'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Answer (score 2):

Use `widget.` to access to the variable in constructor:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = widget.defaultTxt;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the widget variable follow `widget.variableName`

You can do

```dart
  late final TextEditingController _controller =
      TextEditingController.fromValue(
          TextEditingValue(text: widget.defaultTxt));
```

Or use initState to assign the `_controller`.